# error continuo con document.querySelector y docuemnt.getElementById

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet"href="./css/normalize.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet"href="./css/style.css"/>
    <script src="./js/app.dev.js"></script>

    <title>Editor de Codigo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <textarea
            onkeypress="update()" 
            id="text" 
            class="text" 
            placeholder="Escribe tu codigo aqui"
        ></textarea>
        <iframe srcdoc="<h1>Hola mundo</h1>"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>


.JS

const text = document.getElementById("#text").value;


const update = () => {
    console.log(text);
    
}
```

Al aplicar el selector document.querySelector("#text") o el document.getElementById("#text) me da error me dice que es null... ya he buscado el error pero no lo encuentro. Si alquien me puede ayudar gracias.He buscado por google y nada. Revisando el HTML veo todo correcto, ademas he cambiado ya el tipo de comillas de dobles a simple y no va.

Comment: El problema es que en la linea del getElementById("#text") tienes que quitar el "#" dejalo asi getElementById("text")

Comment: muchas gracias por tu colaboracion

Answer (score 1):

En Javascript puro, para seleccionar por `id` pones directamente el id del elemento, sin anteponer `#`, como sí debe hacerse en el caso de usar `querySelector` o en el caso de jQuery.

Pero hay otro problema en tu código. Tú obtienes el `value` del elemento al tiempo que lo seleccionas por `id`, al hacer esto:

```
var text = document.getElementById("text").value;
```

Ahí la variable no es interactiva, se quedará **siempre** con el `value` que tenía en ese momento y no cambiará más. Incluso si la referencia al elemento se crease dentro del contexto dinámico, si la creas directamente con el `value` y necesitaras obtener otra propiedad del elemento (como el `placeholder` por decir algo), **esa referencia ya no te sirve, tendrías que crear otra, y, lo que es peor, volver a MOLESTAR al DOM para eso...** Por eso en Javascript las buenas prácticas recomiendan **crear siempre referencias a los elementos sin más, una sola vez** y luego en el contexto dinámico apelar a los valores u otras propiedades usando la referencia creada. En este caso precisamente interesa ir conociendo el valor dentro de la función.

```js
/*Sólo creamos referencia al elemento sin más*/
var text = document.getElementById("text");

const update = () => {
    /*Obtenemos cada vez el value*/
    console.log(text.value);
}
```

```html
        <textarea
            onkeypress="update()" 
            id="text" 
            class="text" 
            placeholder="Escribe tu codigo aqui"
        ></textarea>
```

---

Con `querySelector` sí se usa `#` para seleccionar por ID:

```js
/*Sólo creamos referencia al elemento sin más*/
var text = document.querySelector("#text");

const update = () => {
    /*Obtenemos cada vez el value*/
    console.log(text.value);
}
```

```html
        <textarea
            onkeypress="update()" 
            id="text" 
            class="text" 
            placeholder="Escribe tu codigo aqui"
        ></textarea>
```

**Otra cosa**: el uso de funciones in-line, como aquí ocurre: `<textarea onkeypress="update()" ...` se considera también una mala práctica. Entre otras cosas hace que el HTML sea dependiente de JS y eso podría traer graves problemas de mantenimiendo. [W3C Recommendation es claro en ese punto y recomienda respetar la *Separación de estructura y comportamiento*.](https://www.w3.org/wiki/The_principles_of_unobtrusive_JavaScript#Separation_of_structure_and_behaviour).

Comment: Muchísimas gracias de verdad, me has ayudado mucho porque ya me tenia agobiado con este código.... Buena tu explicación.... Gracias Gracias

Comment: @Miguel considera marcar la respuesta si la misma ha servido para solucionar tu problema, para que la pregunta no aparezca como sin resolver. Me alegro de haberte ayudado. Saludos.